# How to set default value in template function in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to realize template function like below. *ret* is a return value which is set after doSomething(). But in doSomething sometimes returns false, so I want to set a default value to *ret*. If *T* is int, *ret* should be 0 and if *T* is string, *ret* should be a empty string. So in this case, how should I set a default value to *T*?

```
T getSomeData() {
  T ret;
  if(doSomething()) {
    ret = XXX(); // XXX is set correctly because I use other library..
  } else {
    ret = ??
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>
T getSomeData() {
  T ret = T();
  if(doSomething()) {
    ret = XXX();
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you. But I should pay attention to the type of T if it is custom class.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking a reason to do otherwise, I'd tend to write something more like:

```
template <class T>
T getSomeData() { 
    return doSomething() ? XXX() : T();
}
```

If you prefer, you can use an `if` statement instead:

```
template <class T>
T getSomeData() { 
    if (doSomething())
        return XXX();
    return T();
}
```

I don't, however, see any advantage to defining a local variable just to hold the return value though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructors.

```
template<typename T>
T getSomeData() {
  T ret = T();
}
```

Comment: That works, even for types `T` without constructors.